Manually reproduce tune object # tidymodels
Issue is I have run several xgb tuning processes already but only saved the results in text format or more precisely the metadata, where model-parameters and performance are saved.
it has following structure:
str(p)
'data.frame': 130 obs. of 10 variables:
$ mtry : int 922 1046 512 1317 675 1303 518 1029 1345 1180 ...
$ min_n : int 34 36 73 89 91 32 73 52 75 93 ...
$ tree_depth : int 44 33 43 37 34 48 25 19 38 41 ...
$ learn_rate : num 0.0236 0.0257 0.0292 0.0254 0.0271 0.023 0.025 0.0226 0.0281 0.0641 ...
$ loss_reduction: num 0.0268 0.745 0.148 0.171 0.0275 ...
$ sample_size : num 0.967 0.947 0.789 0.825 0.973 0.521 0.798 0.813 0.993 0.959 ...
$ .metric : chr "mn_log_loss" "mn_log_loss" "mn_log_loss" "mn_log_loss" ...
$ .estimator : chr "binary" "binary" "binary" "binary" ...
$ mean : num 0.423 0.424 0.424 0.424 0.424 0.425 0.425 0.426 0.427 0.427 ...
$ std_err : num 0.000382 0.000439 0.000408 0.000344 0.000368 0.000407 0.000386 0.000398 0.000392 0.000441 ...

Now I want to use the metadata as an initial for a tune_bayes operation:
Error in check_initial():
! initial should be a positive integer or the results of [tune_grid()]
Run rlang::last_trace() to see where the error occurred.

How can I bring the meta-data into a tune-object without re-running computations?
Here is a reproducable example:
param represents the meta data I have, which I want to feed into tune_bayes without tuning again, as this is too time-costly.
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels) 

data(cells)
set.seed(123)
df_split <- initial_split(cells %>% select(-case))
df_train <- training(df_split)
df_test  <- testing(df_split)

set.seed(123)
df_train_folds <- vfold_cv(df_train, v = 5)


# /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

recipe_df <- recipe(class ~ ., data=df_train) %>% 
  step_zv(all_predictors()) %>% 
  step_normalize(all_numeric_predictors())

prep(recipe_df)

xgb_prep<- prep(recipe_df,verbose=T)


# Create model

xgb_spec <- boost_tree(
  trees = 100,
  tree_depth = tune(),
  min_n = tune(),
  mtry = tune(),
  loss_reduction = tune(),
  sample_size = tune(),
  learn_rate = tune(),
) %>%
  set_engine('xgboost') %>%
  set_mode('classification')


# Merge into workflow
xgb_wf <- workflow() %>% 
  add_model(xgb_spec) %>% 
  add_recipe(xgb_prep)

# set ranges for parameters
xgb_params <-
  parameters(xgb_wf) %>%
  update(learn_rate = learn_rate(c(0.01, 0.3), trans=NULL),  # range for the learning rate
         tree_depth = tree_depth(c(3, 100)),  # range for the tree depth
         min_n = min_n(c(1, 10)),  # range for the minimum number of observations
         loss_reduction = loss_reduction(c(1, 5),trans=NULL),  # range for the loss reduction
         sample_size= sample_prop(c(0.5,1)),
         mtry = finalize(mtry(), df_train))

param <- tibble(mtry = c(36,27), min_n = c(8,25), tree_depth = c(4,6), learn_rate = c(0.116,0.000000111), loss_reduction = c(11.5406445593368101,0.0000001105066459), sample_size = c(0.306 ,0.984 ), metric = "mn_log_loss", estimator = "binary", mean = c(0.404,0.420), std_err = c(0.0137,0.0171))


options(tidymodels.dark = TRUE)
set.seed(123)

xgb_res <-
  tune_bayes(
    xgb_wf,
    resamples = df_train_folds,
    param_info = xgb_params,
    initial = param,
    iter =5,
    metrics = metric_set(mn_log_loss),
    control = control_bayes(verbose = TRUE,
                            parallel_over = "everything",
                            no_improve = 10)
  )  

Here is the documentation of tune_grid: https://github.com/tidymodels/tune/blob/main/R/tune_grid.R It did not get me far.
Thanks!

It's hard to give you an exact answer since there is no code but I suspect that the issue is that the mtry parameter does not know what the upper range is (since it is based on the number of predictors in the data). Grid search can kind of figure that out but Bayesian optimization needs you to set it.
You can get the parameter information out of your model specification, set the range of mtry, and then use the tune object (not a data frame) as the input to tune_bayes() along with the parameter information.
Here's an example:
library(tidymodels)

set.seed(1)
sim_tr <- sim_regression(250)
sim_rs <- vfold_cv(sim_tr)

xgb_spec <- 
  boost_tree(mtry = tune(), min_n = tune(), trees = 20) %>% 
  set_mode("regression")

set.seed(2)
initial_res <- 
  xgb_spec %>% 
  tune_grid(
    outcome ~ .,
    resamples = sim_rs,
    grid = 10
  )
#> i Creating pre-processing data to finalize unknown parameter: mtry

# Use the tune object `initial_res` as the input

# Set parameter range for mtry: 

xgb_param <- 
  xgb_spec %>% 
  extract_parameter_set_dials()

# See 'Model parameters needing finalization:' below
xgb_param
#> Collection of 2 parameters for tuning
#> 
#>  identifier  type    object
#>        mtry  mtry nparam[?]
#>       min_n min_n nparam[+]
#> 
#> Model parameters needing finalization:
#>    # Randomly Selected Predictors ('mtry')
#> 
#> See `?dials::finalize` or `?dials::update.parameters` for more information.

xgb_param <- 
  xgb_param %>% 
  update(mtry = mtry(c(1, 20)))

set.seed(3)
bayes_res <- 
  xgb_spec %>% 
  tune_bayes(
    outcome ~ .,
    resamples = sim_rs,
    initial = initial_res,    # <- tune object
    iter = 4,
    # Provide parameter information: 
    param_info = xgb_param
  )

show_best(bayes_res)
#> Warning: No value of `metric` was given; metric 'rmse' will be used.
#> # A tibble: 5 × 9
#>    mtry min_n .metric .estimator  mean     n std_err .config               .iter
#>   <int> <int> <chr>   <chr>      <dbl> <int>   <dbl> <chr>                 <int>
#> 1    18     9 rmse    standard    16.3    10   1.01  Preprocessor1_Model04     0
#> 2    13     5 rmse    standard    16.8    10   0.935 Preprocessor1_Model09     0
#> 3    16    10 rmse    standard    16.9    10   0.940 Iter2                     2
#> 4    20    14 rmse    standard    17.0    10   1.26  Iter1                     1
#> 5    12    16 rmse    standard    17.3    10   1.13  Preprocessor1_Model02     0

Created on 2024-04-23 with reprex v2.1.0

I included a reproducable example, which narrows my question down.
I want to avoid tune_grid as I already have the results in form of the meta-data. If I understand your suggestion right it still leads me to tuning, which is not feasable in my aplication. Could you take a look at the example again?
Thanks!
